# in angular, how do I know when the model is rendered already in html

Tags: angularjs

Currently I am using the angular to build a prototype application, I have a list of person to show, therefor I built a model for the person. when the people 's list is loaded from the http, the model is rendered. This works well

```
<li class="person" ng-repeat="person in people" >
   <h1>{{person.displayname}}</h1>
     <div class="knockout">
        <div id="person-{{person.displayname}}"></div> // to add d3.js svg
      </div>    
</li>
```

now what I need additionally is as soon as the model is rendered, to use d3.js to add another svg layer on top of the original html.

However, as the code shown below, when the model is updated, I tried to add svg for each html, but it doesn't work since at that time, the html of model is not rendered

```
    $http.get(href).success(function(data) {                
        $scope.people= data.people; // update the model
            var svg = d3.select('#person-'+data.people[0].name)
                   .append("svg");          
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    });
```

currently what I do is to set a timeout for adding the svg for each html element, but it is better for me to get notified as soon as the model 's html is rendered completely

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you people array is rendered after the success method is left. That is normal angular behavior, because their is no way in JavaScript to intercept your code. Angular checks for changes when your callbacks finished. At the time you try to append you svg stuff, non of the ids are present in the DOM.

You could use `$scope.$watchCollection("people", function () { ...` and render your stuff in the callback, but binding functionality to ids works against the way angular works. Try to find an angular wrapper for d3.js that you can use it without ids and as a directive.